# question about PHP Vs Actionscript ..?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

First of all, I have a complicated requirement!

and Im not sure it will possible or not, so please read my requirement.

What I want is I've a flash xml widget(created myself!) works like when I post a new article it'll be displayed in that widget through accessing rss. Then I placed it my website for visitors can publish it there site as a widget, the real requirement is coming now, I want to add a "pcode"(pcode means like utm tag, see the example `http://www.mysite.com/?pcode=demo` in this url "demo" is the pcode) after the ending of each links from the article widget title(note: its an swf).

So there is a 'variable' for pcode sets by php guy.

So I want to pass that variable from php to Actionscript and it should display at the end of the article url like `/?pcode=varible`

And my Actionscript is given below

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

var xml:XML;

function onLoaded(e:Event):void
{
var style:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
var no = "rsswidget";
style.setStyle(".heading", {fontWeight:"bold", color:"#6184b7", fontSize:12});
style.setStyle(".readmore", {fontWeight:"normal", color:"#6184b7", fontSize:11});

xml = new XML(e.target.data);
    var il:XMLList = xml.channel.item;
    for(var i:uint=0; i<il.length(); i++)
    {

t.setStyle("styleSheet", style);
t.htmlText = "<a href='"+il.link.text()[0]+'?utm_source=rsswidget'+"' class='heading'>"+il.title.text()[0]+"</a>"+"\<br />"+il.description.text()[0]+"\<br>"+"<a href='"+il.link.text()[0]+'?utm_source=rsswidget'+"' class='readmore'>"+'Read more »'+"</a>"+"\<br />_____________________<br /><br />"+"<a href='"+il.link.text()[1]+'?utm_source=rsswidget'+"' class='heading'>"+il.title.text()[1]+"</a>"+"\<br />"+il.description.text()[1]+"\<br>"+"<a href='"+il.link.text()[1]+'?utm_source=rsswidget'+"' class='readmore'>"+'Read more »'+"</a>"+"\<br />_____________________<br /><br />"+"<a href='"+il.link.text()[2]+'?utm_source=rsswidget'+"' class='heading'>"+il.title.text()[2]+"</a>"+"\<br />"+il.description.text()[2]+"\<br>"+"<a href='"+il.link.text()[2]+'?utm_source=rsswidget'+"' class='readmore'>"+'Read more »'+"</a>";
    }

}

loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.mysite.com/RSS/index-rss.php"));
```

Is that something practical..? I know its complicated!

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Although feel free to ask any further clarifications needed..

Thanks in Advance

Paul

Comment: Let me see if i got this straight, you want to make a call to a php script and get the value of a variable (in the php code) back to flash?

Comment: you're right like this loadVariableNum("variablepage.php",0), I tried this but it wont work in my as3

Comment: loadVariablesNum is an AS2-specific method and won't, therefore, work in AS3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) class.  It can load all sorts of data, including url-encoded variables.

Comment: thanks weltraumpirat for the answer, can you explain how to do that..?

Comment: Basically just like the code you posted above, that's why I didn't elaborate further. Here's an example: http://tush.wordpress.com/2007/07/20/actionscript-3-using-urlloader-to-send-and-load-server-variables/

Comment: okay but I think its just opposit what I want, is there something we can do in our flash like usiong the code below loadVariableNum("variablepage.php",0),  the following one means (variablepage.php = where we get from the variables)

Comment: It is just that.  Instead of using loadVariablesNum, use URLLoader, just like in the example I posted.  You will be able to access all the variables directly from the URLLoader's data property.

Comment: Hey weltrampirat, atlast I found a solution I got 'FlasVar' property to pass the variable from html to flash movie, here it is it'll be a referance for you too..
http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashVars/indexAs3.html

Comment: @Paul: Thanks, but that wasn't really what you asked for - in your example, the call to the PHP script was made from within the Flash movie...